# How to convert xml InputStream to petty-print intend?

Tags: java, xml, stax

I have an `InputStream` with `XML` content. With regards to memory and performance: what is the best way in `java` to convert the stream into a pretty-print (intended) xml string for logging?

`apache-cxf` making use of `Stax`:

```
import org.apache.cxf.staxutils.PrettyPrintXMLStreamWriter;
import org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils;

InputStream in; //assume given

StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
XMLStreamWriter xwriter = StaxUtils.createXMLStreamWriter(sw);
xwriter = new PrettyPrintXMLStreamWriter(xwriter, 2);
StaxUtils.copy(new StreamSource(in), xwriter);
sw.toString();
```

`java.xml.transform`:

```
InputStream in; //assume given

StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
StreamResult xmlOutput = new StreamResult(stringWriter);

TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
transformerFactory.setAttribute("indent-number", 2);
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

transformer.transform(new StreamSource(in), xmlOutput);
xmlOutput.getWriter().toString();
```

Maybe there are other good approaches. The question is: with regards to high throughput and memory consumption, which one is to be favored?

Logging is like:

```
private static final org.slf4j.Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyLogging.class);
LOGGER.info(xmlPrettyPrint);
```

Comment: Whichever way you go: write the output directly to a stream that you want the XML to end up and don't convert to a `String` in between. Because that guarantees that you need at least as much memory as the whole XML takes, which could be avoided by writing directly to a stream.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to go through the `org.slf4j.Logger` interface, which only accepts strings for logging.

Comment: If the data is small enough to be sensibly logged (it's not many megabytes of XML, is it?), then the performance shouldn't be such a big issue. Have you verified that this is actually a bottleneck?

Comment: They are simple xml web requests (not files), but I would want to chose the best approach out of the tons of suggestions pretty-printing xml in java.